# Object detection project (root architecture) using Tensorflow + Keras. Image sample size for accurate training of model?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

Im currenty working on a project at University, where we are using python + tensorflow and keras to train an image object detector, to detect different parts of the root system of Arabidopsis.

Our current ressults are pretty bad, as we do only have about 100 images to train the model with at this moment, but we are currently working on cultuvating more plants in order to get more images(more data) to train the tensorflow model.

We have implemented the following Mask_RCNN model:[Github- Mask_RCNN tensorflow](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) 
We are looking to detect three object clases: stem, main root and secondary root.
But the model detects main roots incorrectly where the secondary roots are located.
It should be able to detect something like this:[Root detection example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrncR.jpg)

Training root data set that we are using right now:[training images](http://www.filedropper.com/train2)

What is the usual sample size that is used to train a neural network accurate results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: I think there is no simple rule to estimate the sample size but at least it depends on:

**1. Quality of your images**

I downloaded the images and I think you need to preprocess them before you can use it to reduce the "problem complexity". In some projects, in which I worked with biological data, a background removal (image - low pass filter) was the key to get better results. But you should definitely remove/crop the area outside the region of your interest (like the tape and the ruler). I would try to get the cleanest data set as possible (including **manually adjustments** cv2/ gimp/ etc.) to focus the network to solve "the right problem".. After that you could apply some random distortion to make it also work on fuzzy/bad/realistic images as well.

**2. The way you work with your data**

There are a few tricks that enables you to "expand" your dataset.
Sometimes it's very helpful to let a generator method **crop random small patches** from your input data. This allows you to work with more batches (on small gpus) and gives your network more "variety", (just think about the conv2d task: if you don't use random cropping your filters will slide over the same areas over and over again (at the same image)). Because of the same reason: **apply random distortion, flip and rotate your images**.

***3. Network architecture***

In your case I would prefer a [U-Net](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py) architecture with a last conv2d output of 3 (your classes) feature maps, a final softmax activation and an categorical_crossentropy, this enables you to play with the depth, because sometimes you need sophisticated architectures to solve a problem (close to 100%) but in your case you just want to see a first working result. So **fewer layers and a simple architecture** could also help you to get things work. Maybe there are some trained network weights for a U-Net which meets your requirements (search on kaggle for example). Because it is also helpful (to reduce the data you need) to use "**transfer learning**" -> use the first layers of an network (weights) which is already trained. Using a semantic segmentation the first filters will become something like an edge detection for the most given problems/images.

***4. Your mental model of "accurate results"***

This is the hardest part.. because it evolves during your project. Eg. in the same moment your networks starts to perform well on preprocessed input images you will start to think about architecture/data changes to make it work on fuzzy images as well. This is why you should start with a feasible problem but always improve your dataset (including rare kinds of roots) and tune your network architecture **step by step**.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will look in to this :)

Comment: Do you have some examples of how to implement my inputs of images plus 3 classes masks and have the output being the segmentation in keras. I'm new to deep learning and do not know too much about keras. Can i just modify the unet/model.py file that you linked to first of all try to train the network architecture?

Comment: And what program do you use to label images and then convert them to mask to be able to train the network? I have used VIA-2.0 and supervise.ly to label the classes in the images this far.

Comment: I have also found this https://github.com/orobix/retina-unet with Unet weights for a retina dataset which look similar to our root system dataset. Could i use their 'test_best_weights.h5' as an input weight when training my dataset?

Comment: Yes you can copy and modify the model.py. If the first x layers of you modified structure match, then you could also reuse the best_weights.h5 of other projects. For image labeling I use sometimes https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme or https://github.com/Labelbox/Labelbox but there are a lot of labeling tools on github (try to find something domain specific) .. but sometimes for small datasets I simply use gimp. This is a bundle of tutorials and stuff to get familiar with keras https://github.com/fchollet/keras-resources very quickly.

Comment: Okey thanks, but what do you mean by the last conv2d output of 3 (your classes) feature maps.

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit clearer if you read a few segmentation tutorials. You need a x dim output of your last layer which matches with the hot encoded label per pixel

Comment: Do i have to use something like "keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)" as error measure between the bitmap masks of the 3 classes(=y_true) and the model prediction(=y_pred), after the last Conv2D layer in the model?